# COUNT from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

This is a funky question, I know this. And maybe it's all because I'm really tired.

Now, don't blame the design - it is flawed, but nothing I can do anything about, ok?

- Two tables, linked by a id-field.
- First table contains positions in a warehouse (table P)
- Second table contains articles stored on each position in the warehouse (table PA)
- *ALL* positions in the warehouse are present in the P-table (> 5000 records)
- Each position *could* contain more than one article
- The are positions in the P-table not present in the PA-table

The count from positionarticles PLUS the positions *not* present in positionarticles.

Is there really no better way than this utter stupidity?:

```
SELECT SUM(row)
FROM
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) row
  FROM PA
  UNION
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM P
  WHERE ID NOT IN
    (
      SELECT P_ID
      FROM PA
    )
) as rowcounter
```

Sample data

*Table P:*

```
ID   Name
1    A01
2    A03
3    B01  *
4    B02  *
```

*Table PA:*

```
ID   P_ID   A_ID
1    1      201  *
2    1      202  *
3    1      203  *
4    2      205  *
```

And the count returned is 6 => 4 rows from PA + 2 rows (P_IDs not present in PA). Rows counted are star-marked (*).

Comment: Can you clarify your question with sample data and expected results?  You say "I want to count ALL positions AND positionarticles".  I would expect two counts to be returned by your query.

Comment: Clarified my questiion, added sample data and expected result. The question is still a bit fuzzy, but should be clear from fuzziness by the sample data. Thx.

Comment: Strawberry: That's not very polite. I've tried a billions (not exactly, but you know, many) versions of JOINs, and the only correct result is in that ugly thing in the q. I'd love to make this work with a normal LEFT or FULL or INNER or CROSS, but I failed, hence my posting here.

Comment: I changed my approach and as many times before; not solving but circumventing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT P.ID, COUNT(PA.ID) noOfArticles
FROM P 
LEFT JOIN PA ON P.ID = PA.P_ID 
GROUP BY P.ID
```

Comment: No, this returns the article count for each position, i.e. it return many rows (positions)